# MYSQL join three tables, selecting two values from two tables

Tags: mysql, join

I'm working on an SQL database and am running into a couple issues.  I admit it is my lack of knowledge, hopefully I can get some assistance.

I have three tables, and I have the following task: "Print the names and majors of students taking x course

the layout is

Student (name, sid), enroll (sid, cno), major (sid, dname)

I thought the following would work, but I keep getting errors

```
SELECT major.dname, student.sname
FROM (select student.sid from student, enroll 
      where student.sid = ernoll.sid and enroll.cno in(461, 462)) l
JOIN major m
ON m.sid = l.sid;
```

I keep getting various errors.

My idea is the nested select gives me a list of student IDs enrolled in either 461 or 462, but I dont' know what to do from there.

I need to join it with Major, so I can get the appropriate student's majors.

Comment: `select name,cno,dname from student,enroll,major where student.sid = enroll.sid and student.sid = major.sid`

Comment: @Flash Thunder .... `and cno in(461, 462)`